# Based on conditional statement add new column to data frame

Tags: r

I have a df

```
a b
0 0
1 1
2 1
0 0
```

I want to add column `c` so that if column `a=1` and `b=1` `c`=`NA`
How can i do it? I tried if and ifelse but i got error 
Thank you

Comment: you can try `c("O", NA)[(a==0) + 1]`

Comment: sorry, I am afraid it does add correctly charachters to column `b`

Comment: To do that, you'll need to actually do the assignment: `df$b <- c("O", NA)[(a==0) + 1]`

Comment: Sorry, your code didnt assign "O" and NA correctly

Comment: @HoHoHo that's what happens when you change your question after someone gives you a hint for an answer... I'm not a mindreader to answer question you didn't ask yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to keep asking more and more questions randomly, but if you just want to target if and only if `b==1 & a==1` then just do.

```
df[which(b == 1 & a == 1),c('c')] <- NA
#df[which(b == 1 & a == 1),]$c <- NA -- alternate.
#df[(b == 1 & a == 1), ]$c <- NA -- another.
```

This will target what you want and also assumes you already have a column `c` created. If not... just create it with a filler of 0 or what you want.

```
df$c <- "filler";
```

Comment: you don't need either `which` and `c` in your first line and you need to tell where to look for the variables (so `df[df$b == 1 & df$a == 1, "c"] <- NA`) and of course, that works only if `c` already exists...

Comment: This just creates a column full of NA.  Of course, that's probably not wrong since we're all guessing at this point

Comment: @RichardScriven not if there is already c in there.

Comment: based on the comment he added to your question "what if in the column c i have some other values" added this answer because OP keeps moving the bar. I feel like this final part will answer the last bit of the question and covers the basis of what seems to be the lack of basics.

Comment: @Cayce K thank yuo very much its what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, c:= 0][a==1 & b==1, c:= NA][]
```